# Applying a function to a list (compounding)

Tags: list-manipulation

I'd like to create a function where it's applied to sections of the listed ranges, while the portions between the "step up" maintain the last value.
For example: If I were to want to apply f[x]=2x to the list {{1,3},{5,7},{9,10}} from 0 to 1 it would be y=0, 1 to 3 would have slope of 2, from region 3 to 5 would have zero slope but still holding y=4 (because (3-1)(2)=4), then 5 to 7 would have increased slope of 2 (y would go from 4 to 8, and then be held constant from 7 to 9) and so on.

(I'm keeping it with the list so that I can edit where I want the function to "step up" and for how long)

Comment: Sorry, it is totally unclear for me want you want. Please try to give a precise mathematical description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are defining the slope of a function to be 2 when it is a member of your intervals, and 0 otherwise. This can be encoded as:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{2, {x} ∈ Interval[{1, 3}, {5, 7}, {9, 10}]}}]
```

Then, you want to integrate this function from 0 to some value `t`:

```
int = Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, t}, Assumptions->t>0];
int //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  4 & 3<t\leq 5 \\
>  8 & 7<t\leq 9 \\
>  10 & t>10 \\
>  2 (t-5) & 9<t\leq 10 \\
>  2 (t-3) & 5<t\leq 7 \\
>  2 (t-1) & 1<t\leq 3
> \end{cases}$

Visualization:

```
Plot[int, {t, 0, 11}]
```

[image]

Comment: very helpful, what if I wanted to vary the rate of increase at each interval?

Comment: Use something like `f[x_] := Piecewise[{{2, 1<x<=3}, {4, 5<x<=7}, {6, 9<x<=10}}]` to have a slope of 2, 4, and 6.

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = {{1, 3}, {5, 7}, {9, 10}};
f[x_] = 2 x;

compound[fn_, list_, x_] := 
  Block[{working = If[list[[1, 1]] == 0, {}, {{c, {0, list[[1, 1]]}}}],
      constantsSet, c}, 
    Do[Block[{}, 
      AppendTo[working, {fn + c, {list[[i, 1]], list[[i, 2]]}}]; 
      AppendTo[working, {c, {list[[i, 2]], list[[i + 1, 1]]}}]], {i, 
      Length[list] - 1}]; 
    AppendTo[working, {fn + c, {list[[Length[list], 1]], 
      list[[Length[list], 2]]}}]; 
    AppendTo[working, {c, {list[[Length[list], 2]], \[Infinity]}}]; 
    constantsSet = {working[[1, 1]], 
      working[[1, 2, 1]] <= x < 
      working[[1, 2, 2]]} /. {Solve[(working[[1, 1]] /. x -> 0) == 0, 
        c][[1]]}; 
    Do[AppendTo[
      constantsSet, {(working[[i, 
        1]] /. {Solve[(constantsSet[[i - 1, 1]] /. {x -> 
        working[[i, 2, 1]]}) == (working[[i, 1]] /. {x -> 
        working[[i, 2, 1]]}), c][[1]]})[[1]], 
        working[[i, 2, 1]] <= x < working[[i, 2, 2]]}], {i, 2, 
        Length[working]}]; 
Piecewise[constantsSet]]

result[x_] = compound[f[x], lst, x]
```

[image]

```
Plot[result[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Should work for any well-defined function and for any set of ranges that are in order and don't touch.